# Problems with printing output C

Tags: c, primes

So I have to write a code for school. I did, but my outputs are not the way they asked for. This code gives me prime number between 2 different numbers. So i have to print those numbers in rows. But yeah there are getting zeros between the answers below you can see what I mean. How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_prime (int number)
{
    int is_prime= 1, i;

    if (number < 2)
    {
        is_prime = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 2; (i * i) <= number; i++)
        {
            if ((number % i) == 0)
            {
                is_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                is_prime = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return is_prime;
}

int main (void)
{
    int lower_limit, upper_limit, i;

    scanf("%d\n%d", &lower_limit, &upper_limit);

    for(i = lower_limit; i <= upper_limit; i++)
    {
        if (is_prime (i))
        {
            printf("\n%d", i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n%d", is_prime(i));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0
11
0
13
0
0
0
17
0
19
0
```

Reference

```
11
13
17
19
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in this `if` block:

```
    if (is_prime (i))
    {
        printf("\n%d", i);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%d", is_prime(i));
    }
```

What this says is "if the number is prime print it, otherwise print whether it is prime (which at this point you've established it's not)".

Just get rid of the `else` block.

Comment: Or get your rubber ducky out

Comment: @JKac - The rubber duck comment comes from [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

If the number is prime number just print it. No else needed - even worse it is incorrect.

You can simplyfy the the is_prime function

```
int is_prime (int number)
{
    int is_prime = number > 1, i;

    for(i = 2; (i * i) <= number; i++)
    {
        if ((number % i) == 0)
        {
            is_prime = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return is_prime;
}


int main (void)
{
    int lower_limit, upper_limit, i;

    scanf("%d\n%d", &lower_limit, &upper_limit);

    for(i = lower_limit; i <= upper_limit; i++)
    {
        if (is_prime (i))
        {
            printf("\n%d", i);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4d8qhx

Comment: Nit - `printf("%d\n", i);` so the program is POSIX compliant, or add a `putchar('\n');` before exit.

Comment: It is op code. I did not change it as it not  something OP asked for

Comment: Yes, that's why I just mentioned it as a nit - otherwise it will screw you prompt up `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Another problem: overflow.

Avoid `int` overflow in `i*i`, which is *undeifned behavior* (UB).
This can happen when `number` is a prime near `INT_MAX`.

```
 // for(i = 2; (i * i) <= number; i++)
 for(i = 2; i <= number/i; i++)
```

A good compiler will see the nearby `number%i` and `number/i` and emit efficient code for the two of them, thus not incurring an expensive 2nd operation.

---

The below also overflows when `upper_limit == INT_MAX`

```
for(i = lower_limit; i <= upper_limit; i++)
```

Perhaps

```
for(i = lower_limit; i - 1 < upper_limit; i++)
```

OK as long as `lower_limit > INT_MIN`.